# Recargar pagina VUE en servidor da error NOT FOUND

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

tengo una pagina en VUE que si la recargo pulsando el F5 del navegador o con un *location. reload()* funcionando sobre el servidor local, se recarga sin problemas.

Pero si hago lo mismo en el servidor de producción, me da "Page Not Found" y tengo que volver al inicio de la aplicación para volver a recargarlo todo.

¿Sabeis como solucionarlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo encontre, modificando el archivo *router/index.js* en el apartado

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: '',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})
```

Yo tenia el *mode: 'history'* y no me permitia el refresco, dejandolo en blanco ya funciona